# Arrays within month

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

My program is currently working to get the next day except I seem to have an array to which I want removing. Whenever I remove the array within my Day property then my month is having an issue. Any ideas for a solution towards this issue. Please do not mention me not wanting to use DateTime or whatever, as I am doing this, as a challenge for myself. Basically the issue is when I remove my array I am having a problem or issue with the month and this array is useless, as I have if statements within my nextDay method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace date
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string british, american; // sets two strings one for british and other for american
            Console.Title = "NextDate Application";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\tNextDate Application\n\t\t\t\t\t-------------------------------------"); // title
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine("This application will allow you to enter a valid date and this will get the next day."); // intro of what the application does
            Console.WriteLine("The application takes leap years into account\n"); // intro of what the application does

            Console.WriteLine("enter key 'b' for British Format or 'a' for American Format"); // writes the line
            char key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

            if (key == 'b') // if key b is entered 
            {
                british = GetValidInput("\nplease enter date as dd/MM/yyyy\n"); // tells user to input a date in the format            

                int day; // sets variable
                int month; // sets variable
                int year; // sets variable
                Date date; // instance of class Date

                string[] read = british.Split('/');  // "/" can be read from each value and sets new array
                day = int.Parse(read[0]); // day is first position in array
                month = int.Parse(read[1]); // month is second position in array
                year = int.Parse(read[2]); // year is third position in array



                try
                {
                    date = new Date(day, month, year); // initialises a new date class

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        date.nextDay(); // calls nextDay method
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Day, date.Month, date.Year); // writes the line in a format of d/m/y
                        Console.ReadLine(); // reads the line
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message); // states the message for ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                    Console.Read(); // breaks
                }
            }

            else if (key == 'a')
            {

                american = GetValidInput("\nplease enter date as MM/dd/yyyy\n"); // tells user to input a date in the format            
                int day; // sets variable
                int month; // sets variable
                int year; // sets variable
                Date date; // instance of class Date

                string[] read = american.Split('/');  // "/" can be read from each value and sets new array
                month = int.Parse(read[0]); // month is first position in array
                day = int.Parse(read[1]); // day is second position in array
                year = int.Parse(read[2]); // year is third position in array

                try
                {
                    date = new Date(day, month, year); // initialises a new date class

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        date.nextDay(); // calls nextDay method
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", date.Month, date.Day, date.Year); // writes the line in a format of m/d/y
                        Console.ReadLine(); // reads the line
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message); // states the message for ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                    Console.Read(); // breaks
                }
            }
        }

        static string GetValidInput(string prompt)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string input;
                Console.WriteLine(prompt);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                {
                    return input;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("error no input");
            }
        }

        class Date
        {
            private int _month; // 1-12
            private int _day; // 1-31 depending on month
            private int _year; // sets the year

            public Date(int day, int month, int year)
            {
                Month = month;
                Day = day;
                Year = year;
            }

            public void nextDay() // nextDay method 
            {

                {
                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 1) // jan
                    {

                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 2;
                    }


                    if (_day == 28 && _month == 2) // feb
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 3;
                    }


                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 3) // march
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 4;
                    }

                    if (_day == 30 && _month == 4) // april
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 5;
                    }

                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 5) // May
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 6;
                    }

                    if (_day == 30 && _month == 6) // June
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 7;
                    }

                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 7) // July
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 8;
                    }

                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 8) // Aug
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 9;
                    }

                    if (_day == 30 && _month == 9) // Sept
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 10;
                    }

                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 10) // Oct
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 11;
                    }

                    if (_day == 30 && _month == 11) // Nov
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _day = _day - 1;
                        _month = 12;
                    }

                    if (_day == 31 && _month == 12) // Dec
                    {
                        _day = 1;
                        _month = 1;
                        _year = _year + 1;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        _day = _day + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            public int Year // property called Year
            {
                get { return _year; } // return the year
                set // set statement
                {
                    if (value >= 1820 && value <= 2020) // if value is higher than or equal to 1820 and less than or equal to 2020
                        _year = value; // sets year as value
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Year must be between 1820 and 2020"); // throws an exception
                }
            }

            public int Month // property called Month
            {
                get { return _month; } // return month
                set // set statement
                {
                    if (value > 0 && value <= 12) // if value is higher than 0 and less than or equal to 12
                        _month = value; // sets month as value
                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Month must be between 1-12"); // throws an exception
                }
            }

            public int Day // property called Day
            {
                get { return _day; }
                set
                {
                    // array  Max days of each month
                    int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

                    if (value > 0 && value <= days[_month]) // if value is higher than 0 and less than or equal to days of month
                        _day = value; // sets day as value

                    // check for the leap year
                    else if (_month == 2 && value == 29 && // else if month is equal to 2 and value is equal to 29
                       (_year % 400 == 0 || (_year % 4 == 0 && _year % 100 != 0)))
                        _day = value;

                    else
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Day is out of range"); // throws an exception
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 11 `_day = _day - 1;` is suspicious in the `switch` table.  And no leap year test in February.

Comment: I know there is no leap year I am going to do that. It's just whenever I remove my array in next day my month stops working. The array is pretty much useless

Comment: There is no array in `public void nextDay()`.  So how can you remove it?

Comment: The _day = _day - 1 is what I had to add. This is because when I left it out the day would auto go to 2 instead of 1 for some reason. @chux

Comment: There is an array in my property for days I mean

Comment: Maybe when `Date()` is called, `property Day set` is called before `_year` is set and that leads to trouble when `_month == 2 && value == 29`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. Each if block is being evaluated independently:

   ```
   if (...)
   {
   }

   if (...)
   {
   }

   else
   {
   }
   ```

   The `else` block here is only paired with the `if` block before it.  Instead, you should be using `else if` in the middle ones.
2. After you make the above change, then you can remove the extraneous `_day = _day - 1;` calls.
3. The February check needs to account for leap year.

   ```
   if (_day == 28 && _month == 2)
   ```

   Should be

   ```
   if (_month == 2 && (_day == IsLeapYear(_year) ? 29 : 28))
   ```

   If you don't want to use `DateTime.IsLeapYear`, then extract your implementation from the `Day` setter into a method and use it in both places.

Regarding your question:

> Whenever I remove the array within my Day property...

The only array in your `Day` property is the one called `days`, which you are indeed using correctly in your logic, so it doesn't make sense to remove it.

Comment: My leap years still is not working even by using DateTime.IsLeapYear?

Comment: I have also used my own implementation which is within my Day setter? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.